# send_to: An invalid argument was supplied

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, tcp, boost-asio

I'm trying to send a Raw TCP packet on the network, using the boost::asio library. My program **works well on Mac OS X 10.8**, but when I run the program under Windows 7 I get an exception (in console): `Error: send_to: An invallid argument was supplied.` The code to open the socket and the `send_to()` method is:

```
try {
    socket_.open();
    socket_.send_to(request_buffer.data(), ep);
} catch (std::exception& e) {
    std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

For defining the endpoint:

```
    ip::address_v4::bytes_type b = {{XXX, XXX, XXX, XXX}};
ip::raw::endpoint ep(boost::asio::ip::address_v4(b), (portnumber);
```

How can I solve the exception, so that the program can run under Windows? In the output window from Visual Studio 2010 the exception is:

```
First-chance exception at 0x000007fefcce9e5d (KernelBase.dll) in (programname).exe: Microsoft C++ exception: boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::system::system_error> > at memory location 0x0,...
```

Comment: What networking library are you using?

Comment: I'm using boost::asio

Comment: Well, then it might be good to mention that in the question. I haven't seen the tag the first time I read the question.

Comment: How are you crafting the packet? Are you using an Ethernet frame or just IP + TCP?

Comment: I'm crafting the packet just like this udp_header.hpp file (https://github.com/kevincon/asio-rawsockets-example), but than only for a tcp packet.

Comment: Is the user you use on windows 7 a member of the administrators group? Now the code-fragment you have posted looks a lot like Kevin Conley's code on github, where he states in the read me that it needs root privileges, which leads me to believe you probably ran it as sudo ./programname on mac. Don't know if that's the error though...

Comment: You should try out [libtins](http://libtins.sourceforge.net), it will solve most of the crafting/sending problems for you.

Comment: The user is a administrator on the PC. Indeed the code looks a lot like Kevin Conley's. I have used it as a start to begin sending a TCP packet. I ran it indeed as sudo ./programname on Mac. It looks like a problem with the right, but what can be done, when the account already is an administrator?

Comment: Just for fun you could right click the program in explorer and choose run as administrator, or if you need to give parameters run the console as administrator and see if that works - if that doesn't work I'm out of suggestions.

Comment: Even that isn't working. From the command prompt (with administrator right) it is also not working. Beside the root privilege, what else can it be?

Comment: Can you post the code that defines and initializes the end point (ep in your code), as well as the socket object.  Try printing out some debug to the console for ep and make sure it is right.

Comment: I have edited my post with the code for defining the endpoint. In debugging mode, my endpoint is set correctly with the right ip-address. It works under Mac OS X, so my code should be right, I think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that RAW TCP sockets are blocked in Windows 7 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/windows/desktop/ms740548(v=vs.85).aspx). Using this link (http://www.savarese.com/software/rocksaw/#Q4) the story has been confirmed and in order to write TCP packets via a raw socket on Windows: you have to open the socket with either IPPROTO_IP or IPPROTO_RAW. Then you have to set the IP_HDRINCL socket option and populate both the IP and TCP headers of each packet. What this means in terms of RockSaw is that on Windows you have to use RawSocket.getProtocolByName("ip") and setIPHeaderInclude(true).

Therefore with Boost::Asio it seems inpossible to send a packet with a own IP-header and a custom TCP packet (see the github of Kevin Conley, named above in a comment)